# How to maintain font styles in json file?

Tags: css, json, spry

I am trying to convert a spry(dreamweaver) table to a json file. The json file is working fine but I can't figure out how to read a paragraph of text(string) and maintain the paragraph's styling. I have mixed bold, italic, and underlines in each paragraph array.{description}

Does anyone know how this is done?

It seems like text styling must be possible, but I'm new to json and feeling a little overwhelmed. I am trying to change to json only because reading the data from a spry table is very slow. I'm developing a mobile app. The data resides on the client side. As it stands now, I load a separate .html page in order to grab the data. That takes too much time on the initial load.

Answer (score 5):

JSON is a plain-text format. It is not possible to save styled text in JSON. You can, however, save marked up text (for instance, with HTML tags, Markdown, etc) in a JSON string just like you would any other piece of text.

Answer (score 1):

A JSON File is a plain text file, so you can't use style fonts, you can use spaces, breaklines. But you can use the same format JSON to insert the kind of style that you want.

Comment: Yep, @Emily wrote the anser before me :)